# C++ does this function cause a undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined, undefined-behavior

Hello i think this is causing an undefined behavior but not sure

```
PlayerMoving *unpackPlayerMoving(BYTE *data)
{
    PlayerMoving *dataStruct = new PlayerMoving;
    dataStruct->packetType = *(int *)(data);
    dataStruct->netID = *(int *)(data + 4);
    dataStruct->characterState = *(int *)(data + 12);
    dataStruct->plantingTree = *(int *)(data + 20);
    dataStruct->x = *(float *)(data + 24);
    dataStruct->y = *(float *)(data + 28);
    dataStruct->XSpeed = *(float *)(data + 32);
    dataStruct->YSpeed = *(float *)(data + 36);
    dataStruct->punchX = *(int *)(data + 44);
    dataStruct->punchY = *(int *)(data + 48);
    return dataStruct;
}
```

does it cause it and if it does how could i fix it ?

this is playermoving

```
struct PlayerMoving
{
    int packetType;
    int netID;
    float x;
    float y;
    int characterState;
    int plantingTree;
    float XSpeed;
    float YSpeed;
    int punchX;
    int punchY;
    int secondnetID;
};
```

and byte is

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Comment: Pedantically (aliasing, object lifetime, ...), it should probably be UB. `memcpy` each member should be better.

Comment: There is no sufficient information shown that would authoritatively conclude whether this is undefined behavior or not. It may be, or it may not be.

Comment: That also assumes some size for `int`/`float`.

Comment: Which is the source of the bytes? (endianess might also be a concern).

Comment: [OT]: Prefer smart pointers over raw owning pointer.

Comment: typedef unsigned char BYTE;

Comment: `dataStruct->x = *(float *)(data + 24);` - but your `struct` seems to have it at `data + 8` or haven't you packaged it in the way the struct is defined? Suggestion: Use fixed width types like `int32_t` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

Even if `BYTE` is an `unsigned char` type (`unsigned char` is an exception to the strict aliasing rule), there is no guarantee that

```
*(int *)(data + 4);
```

and so on meets the alignment requirements for an `int`.

Your best bet is to `memcpy` the data from the `BYTE` array to each structure member, and trust the compiler to optimise (check the generated assembly).

Answer (score 0):

The code causes undefined behavior if any of the following assumptions are violated:

- `BYTE` is `char` or `unsigned char`
- none of your array access go out of bounds
- your implementation allows unaligned accesses, OR the required alignments of `int` and `float` do not exceed 4 bytes AND your array starts at an appropriately aligned address
- no bit patterns are invalid for `int` and `float` on your platform, OR these patterns do not appear in your array

You shouldn't return an allocated raw pointer though. Use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Whereas it should work on most compiler, I think that **pedantically**, there are many source of possible UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 note that compilers are free to define UB, as well. It's not always clear whether something is actually UB in reality, or whether it's IB.

Comment: @user253751: Or whether it's an action which the authors of the Standard saw no need to explicitly provide for, because they failed to imagine that an implementation whose designer wasn't deliberately obtuse would do anything else.

Comment: @supercat I believe the standard generally does specify those. When things are explicitly UB, it's for a reason.

Comment: @user253751: The reason *is* that there was no perceived need to explicitly describe the actions in the Standard.  According to the published Rationale, while the authors of the Standard were deciding how to treat promotion of unsigned types smaller than `int`, they observed that "most current implementations" would treat many forms of signed arithmetic and unsigned arithmetic identically, even in cases where the high bit of the result would become set, unless the results were used in certain ways.  There was no need to have the Standard explicitly say that constructs like...

Comment: ...`uint1 = ushort1 * ushort2;` should be processed using unsigned arithmetic, because that's how modern implementations would process them.  A compiler for a target whose multiply instruction was only useful up to INT_MAX might by default generate code that would only work up to that value, and might only include an option to support larger values if customers demand it, but general-purpose compilers for commonplace platforms were expected to treat `uint1 = ushort1*ushort2;` as equivalent to `uint1 = (unsigned)ushort1 * ushort2;` with or without a mandate.